# Looking up a value based on other values

Tags: r

I’m trying to replicate what (I think) is a fairly trivial thing to do in excel, that I can’t get my head round in R. 
I have a lookup table with several adjustment factors in it – these are dependent on sex and age. I’ll simplify it down to just a few categories

```
+------+--------+--------+---------+---------+-------+-------+
| Code | M_0_15 | F_0_15 | M_16_30 | F_16_30 | M_30+ | F_30+ |
| X1   | 0.1    | 0.2    | 0.4     | 0.5     | 0.5   | 1     |
| X2   | 0.3    | 0.3    | 0.4     | 0.5     | 0.5   | 1     |
| X3   | 0.5    | 0.3    | 0.3     | 0.4     | 0.5   | 1     |
+------+--------+--------+---------+---------+-------+-------+
```

So in my parent dataset (the one I want to add to) I would have something like

```
+------+-----+-----+
| Code | Age | Sex |
| X2   | 16  | M   |
| X2   | 30  | F   |
| X1   | 60  | M   |
+------+-----+-----+
```

I can ask excel to vlookup code X2, and on the basis that the age is 16 and the sex is M (I achieve this through concatenation and an additional lookup)  the column reference is 4 (counting from the left).

This vlookup formula in a new column (adjustment factor) should return a factor of 0.4 which I can go on to use. Pasting it down would give:

```
+------+-----+-----+-------------------+
| Code | Age | Sex | Adjustment_factor |
| X2   | 16  | M   | 0.4               |
| X2   | 30  | F   | 0.5               |
| X1   | 60  | M   | 0.5               |
+------+-----+-----+-------------------+
```

I understand using merge to ‘lookup’ whole ranges of values and create larger datasets (e.g. matching in postcodes to another geography) but I simply can’t get my head around this sort of ‘compound’ looking up.

I think what I need to do is iterate through each observation (cell, in excel) and create a new value in a new column based on if age = x and sex = y then adjustment code = z but I’m drawing a blank with functions such as merge and match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this. The part of the `Age` is what complicates the code.

```
d2$Adjustment_factor= apply(d2,1,function(x){
  ic = which(d1$Code==x[1])                  # select code row
  is = grep(x[3],names(d1))                  # select sex cols
  ia = ifelse(x[2]<16,2,ifelse(x[2]>30,6,4)) # select first age col
  icol = intersect(is,ia:(ia+1))             # col is intersection of sex and age (ia:(ia+1) takes both cols)
  d1[ic,icol]
})

> d2
  Code Age Sex Adjustment_factor
1   X2  16   M               0.4
2   X2  30   F               0.5
3   X1  60   M               0.5
```

**data**

```
> dput(d1)
structure(list(Code = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), M_0_15 = c(0.1, 0.3, 
0.5), F_0_15 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.3), M_16_30 = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.3), 
    F_16_30 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.4), `M_30+` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), `F_30+` = c(1, 
    1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(d2)
structure(list(Code = c("X2", "X2", "X1"), Age = c(16, 30, 60
), Sex = c("M", "F", "M"), Adjustment_factor = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.5
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Many thanks for a quick reply. I'll have to work through that example - it seems insanely complex for what is a simple function in excel.

Comment: The only thing that makes it complicated is the `age`, as it differs in format from the first two cases to the last (60+)